# How to use GitHub Actions to pull specfic files from someone else's repository when they get updates?

Tags: yaml, github-actions

I'd like to utilize Github Actions to pull specific files from another repo whenever they get updated.

What I tried to do is:

1. Pull specific files from someone else's repo (and use a token if it's a private repo).
2. Rename some of those files.
3. Create a PR with them in my repo.
4. Allow to control whether to do manually or also automatically (when the source repo updates itself).

If I somehow missed older questions about it, remember it needs to use the latest Node version due to Github's blockage of older Node versions.

Sample code (trying to pull from a public repo) is below (with v3 in actions/checkout@v3 in an attempt to use the latest Node), but how to make it trigger when someone else's repo updates its files?

Sample code (**Updated**):

```
name: Pull File from Another Repository on Push
env:
  SOURCE_REPO: https://github.com/some/repo
  AUTOMATIC_MONITOR: true
  FILES: "*.txt,LICENSE" # seperate multiple entries with ,
  FILES_NEW: "*.txt,LICENSE*" # seperate multiple entries with ,
  EXTRA: mv LICENSE LICENSE_some_repo # do an extra command like renaming
  USERNAME: ${{ github.actor }}
  ADDRESS_SUFFIX: users.noreply.github.com
  # TOKEN_NAME: ACCESS_TOKEN # uncomment to use a secret with that name
  # SOURCE_BRANCH: source_alternate # uncomment to not monitor the default branch
  # TARGET_BRANCH: target_alternate # uncomment to not push to default branch

on: # Remove # below for non default branches
  workflow_dispatch:
#    inputs:
#      source_branch:
#        description: '${{ env.SOURCE_BRANCH }}'
#        required: false
  push:
#    branches:
#      - ${{ env.SOURCE_BRANCH }}
    paths:
      - ./source-repo/**

jobs:
  pull-file:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check whether to automatically monitor
        if: ${{ github.event_name != 'workflow_dispatch' && env.AUTOMATIC_MONITOR == false }}
        run: |
          exit 1

      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Pull File
        env:
          # THE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.$TOKEN_NAME }}
          EVENT_NAME: ${{ github.event_name }}
          SOURCE_BRANCH: ${{ github.event.inputs.source_branch }}
          REF: ${{ github.ref }}
        run: |
          #!/bin/sh
          
          if [ -n "$TOKEN_NAME" ]; then
            REPO_URL=https://$THE_TOKEN@$SOURCE_REPO.git
          else
            REPO_URL=$SOURCE_REPO.git
          fi
          
          if [ "$EVENT_NAME" = "workflow_dispatch" ]; then
            if [ -n "$SOURCE_BRANCH" ]; then
              git clone -b $SOURCE_BRANCH $REPO_URL source-repo
            else
              git clone $REPO_URL source-repo
            fi
          else
            git clone -b $REF $REPO_URL source-repo
          fi
          cd source-repo
          $EXTRA
          cp -u $FILES_NEW ../
          cd ..

      - name: Commit
        run: |
          git config user.name "$USERNAME"
          git config user.email "$USERNAME@$ADDRESS_SUFFIX"
          git add $FILES_NEW
          git commit -m "Pulled files from $SOURCE_REPO."

      - name: Push
        run: |
          if [ -n "$TARGET_BRANCH" ]; then
            git push origin $TARGET_BRANCH
          else
            git push
          fi
```

Comment: GitHub Script has been updated all te way to `https://github.com/actions/github-script/releases/tag/v6.4.1`, so reference it using: `uses: actions/github-script@v6`

Comment: GitHub Script is written in Javascript, not bash/sh. Just replace the whole action with `name: Pull File
 run: |`

Comment: Be aware that your current workflow is *very* sensitive to script injections attacks. Instead of inlining `${{ env.TOKEN_NAME }}` in your scripts, pass the values through the `env` section instead. See: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/security-hardening-for-github-actions#understanding-the-risk-of-script-injections

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I've added a second sample that combines what you wrote, but this time it complains about the username, could you see the revised question?

Comment: Why did you comment this out? `# THE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.$TOKEN_NAME }}`?

Comment: Because I found no way to add an if statement there and for public repos a token isn't supposed to be needed.

Comment: I've updated v2 in the question and now the issue is in the commit (detailed in the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So since it seems repositories can't be tracked by other repositories' GitHub Actions, I've come up with the following code that:

1. Runs manually if needed.
2. Automatically (can be turned off) monitors your own pushes, only specific branches and folders if needed.
3. Upon a push grabs another repository's files - it can use tokens for private repos and/or if needed grab specific branches.
4. It renames the files you want and - only if they're updated - copies them to your own repo.
5. Only if they're updated - re-commits and re-pushes them to your repo (thankfully [GitHub has loop protection](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/26970#discussioncomment-3254152)).

The only thing I would hope is to find a way to only define branches and paths for the push monitoring if they're needed instead of commenting them out if they're not needed.

The code:

```
name: Pull Files from Another Repository on Push
env:
  SOURCE_REPO: owner/repo
  AUTOMATIC_MONITOR: true
  FILES: "*.txt,LICENSE" # seperate multiple entries with ,
  FILES_NEW: "*.txt,LICENSE*" # seperate multiple entries with ,
  EXTRA: mv LICENSE LICENSE_some_repo # do an extra command like renaming
  USERNAME: ${{ github.actor }}
  ADDRESS_SUFFIX: users.noreply.github.com
  TOKEN_NAME: ACCESS_TOKEN # name of token defined in the target repo's settings, needed for private repos
  # SOURCE_BRANCH: source_alternate_branch # uncomment to takes files from a non default source branch
  # TARGET_BRANCH: target_alternate_branch # uncomment to monitor a non default target branch
  # TARGET_PATH: target_alternate_path # uncomment to monitor a non default target branch
  THE_SERVER: ${{ github.server_url }}
  PATH_SOURCE_CHECKOUT: temp_folder
  THE_SECRET: ${{ secrets.TOKEN_NAME || 'default_value' }}

on: # Remove # below for non default branches
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
#    branches:
#      - ${{ env.TARGET_BRANCH }}
#    paths:
#      - ${{ env.TARGET_PATH }}

jobs:
  pull-file:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check whether to automatically monitor
        if: ${{ github.event_name != 'workflow_dispatch' && env.AUTOMATIC_MONITOR == false }}
        run: |
          echo "Set not to run automatically. Exiting."
          echo "exiting1=true" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Checkout
        if: env.exiting1 != 'true'
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Checkout source with token and branch
        if: env.exiting1 != 'true' && env.THE_SECRET != 'default_value' && env.SOURCE_BRANCH
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          repository: ${{ env.SOURCE_REPO }}
          ref: ${{ env.SOURCE_BRANCH }}
          token: ${{ secrets[env.TOKEN_NAME] }}
          path: ${{ env.PATH_SOURCE_CHECKOUT }}

      - name: Checkout source with token but without branch
        if: env.exiting1 != 'true' && env.THE_SECRET != 'default_value' && !env.SOURCE_BRANCH
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          repository: ${{ env.SOURCE_REPO }}
          token: ${{ secrets[env.TOKEN_NAME] }}
          path: ${{ env.PATH_SOURCE_CHECKOUT }}

      - name: Checkout source without token but with branch
        if: env.exiting1 != 'true' && env.THE_SECRET == 'default_value' && env.SOURCE_BRANCH
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          repository: ${{ env.SOURCE_REPO }}
          ref: ${{ env.SOURCE_BRANCH }}
          path: ${{ env.PATH_SOURCE_CHECKOUT }}

      - name: Checkout source without token and without branch
        if: env.exiting1 != 'true' && env.THE_SECRET == 'default_value' && !env.SOURCE_BRANCH
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          repository: ${{ env.SOURCE_REPO }}
          path: ${{ env.PATH_SOURCE_CHECKOUT }}

      - name: Update
        if: env.exiting1 != 'true'
        run: |
          cd $PATH_SOURCE_CHECKOUT
          $EXTRA
          cp -u $FILES_NEW ../
          cd ..

      - name: Check for changes
        if: env.exiting1 != 'true'
        run: |
          if git diff --quiet; then
            echo "No changes detected. Exiting."
            echo "exiting2=true" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          fi
          
      - name: Commit
        if: env.exiting1 != 'true' && env.exiting2 != 'true'
        run: |
          git config user.name "$USERNAME"
          git config user.email "$USERNAME@$ADDRESS_SUFFIX"
          git add $FILES_NEW
          git commit -m "Pulled files from $THE_SERVER/$SOURCE_REPO."

      - name: Push
        if: env.exiting1 != 'true' && env.exiting2 != 'true'
        run: |
          if [ -n "$TARGET_BRANCH" ]; then
            git push origin $TARGET_BRANCH
          else
            git push
          fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You're left with needing a safe way to pass the credentials to Git.

You can set a custom credential manager to pass these details from the environment:

```
git config --global credential.helper "!f() { echo \`"username=`${GIT_USER}`npassword=`${GIT_PASS}\`"; }; f"
```

That will allow you to pass the credentials safely from the environment variables into git, without having to inject the token into the remote url:

```
run: |
  REPO_URL=$SOURCE_REPO

  git config --global credential.helper "!f() { echo \`"username=`${GIT_USER}`npassword=`${THE_TOKEN}\`"; }; f"

  if [ "$EVENT_NAME" = "workflow_dispatch" ]; then
    if [ -n "$SOURCE_BRANCH" ]; then
      git clone -b $SOURCE_BRANCH $REPO_URL source-repo
    else
      git clone $REPO_URL source-repo
    fi
  else
    git clone -b $REF $REPO_URL source-repo
  fi
  cp source-repo/{$FILES} .
  $EXTRA
```

You'll need to pass the token to the push step too, it might be simpler to declare them at the job level instead:

```
jobs:
  pull-file:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      GIT_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.$THE_TOKEN}}
      GIT_USER: ${{ vars.GIT_USER }}
```

Your commit step should beleverage the custom credential manager we've setup in the pull step.

Comment: Please provide the full code as an answer. For example, you set GIT_TOKEN but then used THE_TOKEN in the run. Also, keep in mind public repos may not need a token so I hoped to pass it only if needed (based on whether I declared it or not in the top env). GIT_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.$TOKEN_NAME }} is a syntax that doesn't work. I'm also not sure what `${{ vars.GIT_USER }}` is because doing echo #GIT_USER produced blank.

Comment: The vars scope is for variables defined at org or repo level. You could move that to the top level env section as well. I'm expecting you to do some work. I'm answering this from my phone in my spare time.

Comment: If you want to make the credential manager optional, you can wrap it in an if statement. I'd use the token in any case, since the anonymous request is subject to much stricter rate limits.

Answer (score -1):

I use a simple `run` command to run a script. Albeit, it won't update when they get an update, but will fetch latest file when your github actions triggers.

```yaml
jobs:
   runs-on: ubuntu-latest
   steps:
     - name: checkout your latest repo
       uses: actions/checkout@v3

    ... your additiona setups here maybe...

     - name: pull latest file
       run: |
         wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repo/file-i-want.json
```

Comment: You wrote just 1 line of code, not sure how it pulls files from another repo, etc.

Comment: bah stupid editing, wanted a newline, but posted instead. blameing it on the noob me.

Comment: Now it makes much more sense, yet unfortunately still doesn't answer the question, as it pulls a static file whether it's on on GitHub or not. You didn't even show the `on:` part to give your full code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).